# PHP has been disabled after installing PHP5-IMAP pacakge

Tags: php, debian, imap

I installed imap pacakge on Debian Wheezy :

```
apt-get install php5-imap
```

For all prompts I choose the default action which is don't override the current version  (N) .

After installing, I open the web app on the server in my browser.  The browser shows the source code of `index.php` without compiling that page.

Why php is disabled?

### UPDATE :

Known also that :

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep php5
```

Output  :

```
libapache2-mod-php5             deinstall
php5                        install
php5-cgi                    install
php5-cli                    install
php5-common                 install
php5-curl                   install
php5-gd                     install
php5-imap                   install
php5-json                   install
php5-mcrypt                 install
php5-mysql                  install
php5-xcache                 install
```

Comment: What does `dpkg --get-selections | grep php5` tell you?

Comment: I add update according to your request :

Comment: try reinstalling libapache2-mod-php5